# Xen 6.2 guest IP Assignment

Tags: xen, xenserver

so basically I have written a provisioning system that provisions from a billing system onto XEN. Right now I am assigning a DHCP IP to the guest on boot. The host access the client server via ssh and runs a few things...One of which is the configuration to the network connections. My requirements dictate that the VLAN must be changed after this process which requires a reboot(time).

So the two things I can't seem to figure out are
A) Can I "Inject" the ip address into the guest without having to utilize SSH(maybe a command?).

B) Can I change VLANs on the guest without having to reboot.(current process powers down, destroys NIC, adds NIC, powers up.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of machine (OS) are you provisioning? Why are you destroying the nic? (My guess: to change the MAC address of the nic?) And is it correct to say that your notion of VLAN is "the lan of my virtual machine"? How many lan interfaces is your virtual machine going to have?

Comment: I am provisioning cent and ubuntu atm but will add more. I am destroying the NIC to change the VLAN of the NIC. I cannot find a way to change it from the CLI or xenapi on a live machine.